# Activating wordpress W3C Cache plugin makes server down

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

As I was working on the site I certainly activated the Deactivated w3c total cache plugin and it takes the server down. As I searched and found that it's .htaccess that causing the issue. I removed the w3c script from .htaccss file but still Server is not working.

Please help me getting server back to it's working position.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Delete advanced-cache.php, db.php, wp-total-cache-config.php, and delete the entire w3tc folder from the Wp-content folder.